# Connecting 2 APs using PoE compatibility concerns

Tags: networking, poe

I would like to set up 2 access points that would be creating WiFi network for me.

My preference was to buy MikroTik hAP ac lite TC (RB952Ui-5ac2nD-TC) with MikroTik mAP (RBmAP2nD). The 1st one would be connected to AC power. 2nd I would like to connect to 1st using 20m ethernet cable and power it with PoE.

Are those 2 devices compatible?

Is 20m cat 6 ethernet cable good?

I guess I need patch cable right?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Hw Recs! In general, our site is designed to provide pre-purchase recommendations for hardware rather than technical details or support. (iex. X for $Y vs. Will X work/is good?)